# Существуют ли рекомендуемые сценарии валидации ключей (паролей) симметричных алгоритмов шифрования

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, теория, aes

Пишу утилиту с функциональностью шифрования файлов симметричными алгоритмами шифрования на выбор. Утилита может шифровать сразу несколько файлов, из зашифрованных байтов которых формируется один файл. Ключ шифрования, как и вектор инициализации, генерируются из введенного пользователя пароля классом Rfc2898DeriveBytes. Помимо алгоритма, в утилите можно выбрать длину ключей, если алгоритм допускает несколько, длину блоков (правда, все симметричные алгоритмы, реализованные в .Net допускают только одну их длину), ChipherMode, PaddingMode и FeedbackSize. Так же в настройках можно указать какие данные о пароле будут доступны в метаданных выходного файла. Утилита допускает включить в метаданные хеш пароля, а так же длину ключа, что позволяет при дешифрации файла валидировать введенный пароль точно, но так же она допускает и отсутствие такой информации в метаданных, а это значит, что в этом случае нет никакой возможности проверить пароль на валидность до попытки дешифровать данные.

Есть ли какие-нибудь практики или рекомендуемые сценарии как лучше действовать в таких случаях?

Мне кажется странным, пытаться дешифровать данные не будучи уверенным в правильности ключа, так как это, в случае неправильного пароля и сгенерированного из него ключа, ведет к исключениям и получению ошибок, что усугубляется еще и тем, что в некоторых случаях дешифрация не валидными ключами даже может пройти и вполне успешно.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что зачастую, проверка валидности пароля делается принципиально "не быстрой", чтобы снизить скорость перебора при брутфорсе. Например, хэш пароля может лежать в распаковываемых данных с большим смещением - что потребует распаковки всего предшествующего, что замедлит перебор.

Comment: Быстрая проверка ключей на правильность - это дыра в безопаности, так как у взломщика появляется простой и быстрый метод подбора паролей. Проверка правильности пароля должна занимать доли секунды, чтобы скорость подбора была не больше десятков ключей в секунду.

Comment: Я думал про все про это, те же самые мысли мне пришли в голову. Но если проверка пароля будет происходить, скажем, 1-2 секунды, то это допустимо для пользователя, и не делает перебор паролей слишком быстрой задачей.